# How can I check my port 23?

Tags: windows-7, vuze

I've installed Vuze and now I'm getting this message sometimes:

```
      On of your application (probably Telnet) appears to be making a potentially unencrypted und unsafe connetion to port 23.
```

I checked my open ports with cports but I cannot find any. I've also looked in the system events to no avail. Where do I need to look in the system events for this message and what is this message meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your machine is telneting somewhere... or at least using going to another host at port 23.  Telnet is unencrypted and not really safe to use since someone running a packet capture (like Wireshark) can see everything you are sending to that port 23.

Answer (score 0):

The `netstat` command in a Command Prompt window will show a list of listening programs and outgoing connections

```
C:\>netstat -ab

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address         State           PID
  TCP    Black:http             Black:0                 LISTENING       1728
  [Apache.exe]
  …
  TCP    Black:2049             stackoverflow.com:http  ESTABLISHED
  [chrome.exe]
```

Comment: Can I sort it like in Linux?

Comment: @David: If you want Windows to be like Linux, you may wish to install Cygwin, unxutils or gnuwin32. Otherwise you'll have to wrestle with weak command-prompt shell & tools or learn PowerShell.

Comment: I have cygwin installed. Can I use it?